# "the temporary folder is missing" file upload error

Tags: file-uploads, error

All of a sudden I've started getting an error message when I try to upload anything. EE just says "The temporary folder is missing."

I've talked with the host, and they've verified that the d:\temp folder exists and is writable.

Has anyone else seen this or have any advice on how to fix it?

Porter.

Answer (score 0):

That's on a windows machine. You have to make double sure php and apache are also aware of the location of the temp folder.